# Databricks "Data"->"Tables" functionality doesn't work

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have created a Databricks cluster with which I read data from ADLS and then create a series of TEMP View in order to do some data transformation with SparkSQL. In the trial version, I was able to create Tables from the final Temp View, which I cannot do now when I have a paid version of Databricks ( I know, that's ironic..).
Another problem I've spotten that in the "Spark UI" -> "SQL", the command "Show DATABASES" is showing up multiple times and runs for as long as 10-15 minutes, sometimes even after I complete with all the Temp View and I write the output data to ADLS. I can't make any sense of it, unfortunately. Did somebody else faced this problem and can help?
I'll attach a photo with what I can see always in the "Data" view from Databricks

[image]

Comment: Things run slowly on db these days.

Comment: open support ticket (against MS if you're on Azure)